# Migration from Struts to Spring

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, migration, struts-1

I am working on a project in which we are migrating from Struts 1.3 to Spring MVC 3.0.

There is a problem with JSP as discussed below:

tag of Struts is used to retrieve collection from Java class.

My question is that...
Is there any tag that can replace **<html:optionsCollection>** tag of struts to Spring MVC?

---

```
<form:select onchange="javascript:changeSelectedType();" property="countryType" styleClass="form-control">                                  
        <html:optionsCollection property="stateType"/>
</form:select></code>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use this :

```
<form:select path="country"> 
   <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---"/>
   <form:options items="${countryList}" />
</form:select>
```

Good luck

Comment: I have tried this thing, but not fruitful. Thanks for suggesting a solution.

Comment: @NishatLakhani Without knowing *how* it failed we can't help; `<form:options>` is the Spring equivalent.

Comment: Happy for you and don't forget +1 :)